# Validating string Pattern for type CC-YY-NNNN

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write the regex for CC-YY-NNNN(PE-19-001). Where CC is a character, YY is the year NNNN could be a 3 or a 4 digit positive number.
There will be exactly two dashes in the string.

So far, what I have tried is :

```
if( value.includes("-") && /\d/.test(value) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(value) && /-\d$/.test('-1') )
```

But I am unable to get any close.

Comment: Why not use  a single pattern to use with `RegExp.test`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a single pattern to match 2 uppercase chars [A-Z], 2 digits and 3-4 digits using a quantifier `{3,4}`

```
^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{3,4}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MjFT01/1)

```js
const regex = /^[A-Z]{2}-\d{2}-\d{3,4}$/;
[
  "PE-19-001",
  "PE-19-0011",
  "P-19-001",
  "PE-1-001"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + regex.test(s)))
```